# Give id to a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have it so that when you (the PaintBrush) hit the finish everything clears and a button appears. When the button is clicked it starts level two, here it creates a new canvas. I've added some code so that when the button is clicked the old canvas is deleted, then the new one is made. However, this requires the canvas to have an id. how do i get this code:

```
canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
```

To also include an id for it? I cannot have it say var canvas = blah blah and then have 
    canvas.id = "canvas";
because of the way i have it set up.

P.S the remove code is this if you need to know:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
        this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
    }
}
}
```

and in the button "click" function area i put this for the remove:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").remove();
```

Please help! Thanks in Advance!

EDIT: Here is some extra code to help, it is what occurs when the PaintBrush hits the finish:

```
else if (PaintBrush.crashWith(Finish)) {
  PaintBrush.y = 50;
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Level 3";
button.id = "button-2";  // add the id to the button
document.body.appendChild(button); // append to body
GameArena2.clear();
GameArena2.stop();
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
startGame2();
document.getElement("canvas").remove();
document.getElementById("button-2").remove();
});
```

EDIT 2: Game canvas code:

```
var GameArena2 = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 1280;
    this.canvas.height = 480;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea2, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
  stop: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  drawGameOver: function() {
    ctx2 = GameArena2.context;
        ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,"+fader +")";
        ctx2.fillRect(0,0,GameArena2.width,GameArena2.height);
        drawStatic(fader/2);
        fader += .1 * 1/fps
        ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + fader + ")";
        ctx2.font = "72px sans-serif";
        ctx2.fillText("GAME OVER",GameArena2.width/2 - 220,GameArena2.height/2);
    }
}
function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((GameArena.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((GameArena.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: can you use jquery?  have you possibilities to create a static function to use?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a static function like this:

```js
function createElementOnDom (type,id) {
   var element=document.createElement(type);
   element.id=id;
   return element;
}

console.log(createElementOnDom('CANVAS','myId'));
```

So you can simply create the canvas adding it his specific id using a simple single row function call like you need.

I only know a way to do direcly this on jQuery, that you wouldn't like to use.

simply you need to do that:

```
function createElementOnDom (type,id) {
       var element=document.createElement(type);
       element.id=id;
       return element;
    }

var GameArena2 = {
  canvas: createElementOnDom('CANVAS','myId'),
```

Comment: this is my Game canvas code, what would i replace with the static function?

Comment: My game canvas code is in Edit 2 of my post, so what part would i replace with this static function?

Comment: @TheCodersZone use the function to create the div, save the id somewhere in a variable and remove it with an 'getElementById().remove' on game end

Comment: @TheCodersZone you only need to add it, and use it to create the canvas and set his id

Comment: would my code still work if i got rid of the canvas: document.createElement("canvas"), ? asking because it has a comma after it, joining it with the other parts of GameArena2

Comment: yes, thats only an object declaration, you can see the comma like a common ;

Comment: i tried this:  var GameArena2 = {
  function canvas (type,id) {
   var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.id= canvas;
   return canvas;
}
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 1280;
    this.canvas.height = 480;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea2, 20);
  }, (etc.)

Comment: new problem, when i press the button i still end up with two canvases, even though no errors show in the console

Comment: if you have a look at this: http://s.codepen.io/TechTime/full/gmYjmO/bZrQWyLDyqbk you can see when you complete level 1 the button appears and it will create an extra canvas

Comment: Please Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Simple!** Just assign it immediately after the `GameArena2` object is created.

```
var GameArena2 = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function() { 
      ...
      ...        
}

// give id to a canvas
GameArena2.canvas.id = "GameArena2";

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((GameArena.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) { 
        ...
        ...        
}
```